# Please write out in simple English without too many key shortcuts like .pop or .include, etc., but I am completely lost as to how to do this

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Write a method `strange_words` that accept an array of strings The method should return an array containing all strings that are either shorter than 6 characters or begin with `"e"`.

```rb
puts strange_words[
  "taco", "eggs", "excellent", "exponential",
  "artistic", "cat", "eat"
]
puts strange_words[
  "elegant", "ellen", "monsterous"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way round would be to use regular expression.

```rb
strange_words = [
  "taco", "eggs", "excellent", "exponential",
  "artistic", "cat", "eat"
]

strange_words.select { |w| w[/\A[^e].{5,}/i] }
#⇒ ["artistic"]

strange_words.reject { |w| w[/\A[^e].{5,}/i] }
#⇒ all but `"artistic"`
```

The regular expression literally means “starts with anything but `"e"` followed by at least five characters (summing up to six+.)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 
  strange_words[
    "taco", "eggs", "excellent", "exponential",
    "artistic", "cat", "eat"
  ]
```

Code

```
puts a.select { |x| x.begin_with?'e' or x.length < 6 }
```